# BackgroundWorker event handlers not called until end of script in FitSharp

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, fitnesse, fitsharp

I am struggling to code a fixture that will test a C# application that is using BackgroundWorker thread. Any help would be much appreciated!

### Details

I am writing fixtures to test a multi-threaded C# application *(.NETv4)* using FitNesse *(v20150814)* and Fitsharp *(v2.2.4498.25493)*.

In the ViewModel, the background worker is setup as follows:

```
        _backgroundWorker = workerFactory.GetBackgroundWorker();
        _backgroundWorker.ProgressChangedEventHandler = BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged;
        _backgroundWorker.DoWorkEventHandler = BackgroundWorkerDoWork;
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler = BackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted;
```

Then, during the user interaction, the worker is kicked off with:

```
        _backgroundWorker.Run(args);
```

In interactive mode, **this works fine**, with the event handlers being called as expected.

**However**, when I initiate the Run() command using a FitNesse fixture, only the DoWorkEventHandler is called as expected.

The other handlers (ProgressChanged, RunWorkerCompleted) are not called until the very end of the test, when, presumably, the FitSharp thread is also completing.

As critical work is node by those other handlers, I am not able to test the outcome of the background worker's work.

A colleague suggested re-structuring the application so that all the work is done in the DoWork event handler, and that *can* work, but I really don't want to go re-working the application if I can avoid it.

---

### Additional information

I analyzed the threads and the call stack and have drawn a diagram to show what appears to be going on.

The problem is that the fitSharp test module is packed up and finished with **before** the final event handlers are called on my worker thread (far right).

[Sequence Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2glHh.png)

The sequence diagram is based on [this thread information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU6tw.png) information.
I can post more details if requested, and apologies for the cramming in the threads image, but I could only post 2 links...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some way to tell `fitSharp` to wait until your background worker is finished before continuing with the next step in your test script. The `wait until` keyword can help do this.  See http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/WaitUntilKeyword.html for details.  You'll need a fixture method that can detect when the background worker is finished.
e.g.

```
|myfixture|
|start worker|
|wait until|worker finished|true|
|check|some result|expected|
```

(`wait until` was added in `fitSharp` version 2.3)

Comment: Thanks for your response, Mike, but I don't think that is my problem. Please check out the *Additional Information* section I just added above.

Comment: I should add, for clarity, that I already have a wait loop in my fixture, and that does work for the initial DoWork event -  just not the later events as described in my additional info above.

Comment: I still think my explanation is correct.  There's nothing to stop the fitsharp thread from running to completion - and that's exactly what your thread information shows.  The fitsharp thread needs something to make it wait for the background worker thread to complete.

Comment: Sorry, Mike. I have confused us both... The sequence diagram shows what happens if I do not wait. If I DO wait, then the script never advances past the wait loop, because the event handlers (after DoWork) are never called. If I then use the debugger to move out of the wait loop, then the later event handlers will fire, but always after the fitsharp script is finished.

Comment: OK.  If you can post a minimum working set of code that reproduces the problem, I can look into it.